# Adding a Model Reference to existing Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'd like to know the "proper" way to approach adding a relation between two *existing* classes in Rails 3.

Given existing models: Clown & Rabbit

I'd like to add a reference (belongs_to) from Rabbit to Clown. I start by trying to generate a migration:

```
rails g migration AddClownToRabbits clown:reference
```

which gives me a migration that looks like:

```
class AddClownToRabbits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :rabbits, :clown, :reference
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :rabbits, :clown
  end
end
```

After `rake db:migrate` on this migration I examine SQLite3's development.db and see a new column: `"clown" reference`

I guess I was expecting a `"clown_id" integer` column and a migration that looked like:

```
class AddClownToRabbits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :rabbits, :clown_id
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :rabbits, :clown_id
  end
end
```

I'm sure :reference is supposed to be equivalent to "t.references :clown" but I can't find the documentation (big surprise). API says add_column: `Instantiates a new column for the table. The type parameter is normally one of the migrations native types, which is one of the following: :primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :timestamp, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean.`

...with no *reference* to :reference.

Comment: For documentation (well, a reference to it in documentation, if that counts) see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and scroll down to 7.1 Generating a Model and look at the code snippet beneath that heading.   You'll see there that it is *:references* rather than *:reference*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After you set belongs_to in Rabbit, and has_many in Clown, you can do a migration with:

```
add_column :rabbit, :clown_id, :integer
```

EDIT: See [Paulo's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16354869/299774) for a more updated answer (Rails 4+)

Comment: great! thanks! i kinda expected that...but still struggling with where to put that... in a 'naked' migration? so maybe just `rails g migration AddClownToRabbits` and then edit rest by hand?

Comment: which i've just tested now...and it does give me a blank slate with proper timestamped filename...that i can edit as you mention. thanks

Comment: I'm under the impression that using "references" also adds an index to the column, but this way would you need to add :index => true. something like this                           add_reference :rabbits, :clown, :index => true

Answer (score 64):

If you are using edge rails (4.0) you can use:

```
rails generate migration AddAddressRefToContacts address:references
```

As you can see by the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Comment: Finally! That was missing since Rails 2

Comment: You could also use `address:belongs_to` if you prefer

Comment: this should have used the original example

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where you got this idea, but there is no (and never has been) such syntax to do what you want with `add_column`. To get the behavior you want, you'd have to do `t.refences :clown`, as you stated. In the background this will call: `@base.add_column(@table_name, "#{col}_id", :integer, options)`.

See [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/references).

EDIT:

I think I can see the source of your confusion. You saw the method call `t.reference` and assumed it was a datatype because calls such as `t.integer` and `t.string` exist, and those are datatypes. That's wrong. Reference isn't a datatype, it's just simply the name of a method, similar to `t.rename` is.

Comment: sorry for the confusion...learning...and, well, this is how you learn. thanks!  So, to answer my question, what IS the proper generator command...still assuming I need to start with one because generators are timestamped and I don't think I should be creating the filename by hand?!? `rails g migration AddClownToRabbits clown:reference` gives me the bad junk above.

Comment: @Meltemi: There is no generator command for adding references, only columns. Keep in mind that all the generator does is..well..generate. It's not a big deal that it can't add references, you just have to do it yourself.