# Ruby on rails: Adding 2 references of a single model to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, database-design, rails-models

I'd like to know a proper way to implement my situation here in ruby on rails 4.0.

Lets say I have 2 models named **House** and **Order**.

My Order table should have two columns **from** and **to** both referencing a house model.

What should my relations between these two models be in this case? 
**Note:** I do not require any reference to order model from house model.

I would like to have something like this in my Order table

```
t.references :house, as:from (this should create a column named from and should be of type integer, index of house table
t.references :house, as:to (this should create a column named to and should be of type integer, index of house table
```

I would like this type of relation in order model because I want to take fields of houses in my order form something like

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  ... # order fields
  <%= f.fields_for :house(from) do |i| %>
    ... # your house forms
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :house(to) do |i| %>
    ... # your house forms
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Is there any specific way to this in rails?

**P.S :** I have already read this post here but I think it does not exactly solve my problem. 
[Adding a Model Reference to existing Rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338973/adding-a-model-reference-to-existing-rails-model?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In create orders migration file:

```
create_table :orders do |t|
  ..
  t.integer :from_house_id
  t.integer :to_house_id
  ..
end
```

In your app/models/order.rb:

```
belongs_to :from_house, class_name: 'House'
belongs_to :to_house, class_name: 'House'

accepts_nested_attributes_for :from_house, :to_house
```

In your views:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  ... # order fields
  <%= f.fields_for :from_house do |i| %>
    ... # your from house forms
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :to_house do |i| %>
    ... # your to house forms
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats exactly what I have been looking for. I think its **accepts_nested_attributes_for** :from_house, :to_house, in order model. I've made that change. After that I tried to implement the above, but the form is not appearing at all. My server doesn't show any error. All the fields in side the fields are not showing. I dont know what the reason is?

Comment: My bad, had a typo in there! Sorry. You need to say `@order.build_from_house` and `@order.build_to_house` in your controller and it will appear! If an answer helps then please accept it as that answer may help someone else in the future as well. :)

Comment: hey Surya, I have one more small issue, Can you please help me with that too? In the above scenario I also have a User model. I have the following relations,  Order belongs_to :user, and User has_many :orders. Similarly. house belongs_to :user and user has_many :houses. I'm also taking f.fields for :user in order form. Everything gets updated well except for the user_id in house model which goes as NULL. I would like that to be the user just created here. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'd be more than happy to help. Please create another question, it's hard to follow up on an issue in comments.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623661/ruby-on-rails-updating-multiple-models-in-a-single-form

Answer (score 0):

Add this answer just in case Surya's code doesn't work - I'm used to having to specify the foreign_key:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_house, :class_name => "House", :foreign_key => "from_id"
  belongs_to :to_house, :class_name => "House", :foreign_key => "to_id"
end
```

Just make sure you have two attributes on `Order` - one being `from_id` and another `to_id`. From now on you can call `order.from_house` and `order.to_house`.