# Ruby on Rails : Updating multiple models in a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have 3 models User, House and Order.

Order Model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :from_house, :class_name => "House"
   belongs_to :to_house, :class_name => "House"
   belongs_to :user

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :from_house, :to_house, :user
end
```

My House Model.

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :city
end
```

My user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :houses
end
```

In my order form I have something like this

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  ... # order fields
  <%= f.fields_for :user do |i| %>
    ... # your from user forms
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :from_house do |i| %>
    ... # your from house forms
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :to_house do |i| %>
    ... # your to house forms
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I haven't changed much in controller from the default. The controller code

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit( :shift_date, user_attributes: [:name, :email, :ph_no], from_house_attributes: [:place_id, :floor, :elevator, :size], to_house_attributes: [:place_id, :floor, :elevator])
    end
```

When I submit the form, as expected a Order gets created with a new from_house and to_house along with a new user. But however my user_id in house table remains NULL. How can I make the houses(both from and to) reference the user created after submit.

The User is not logged in, So there is no current_user. We have to create a new user based on the details given. That user has to be associated with the houses (from and to).

I hope I'm clear. If not please let me know.

P.S: This question is an extension to this [Ruby on rails: Adding 2 references of a single model to another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611918/ruby-on-rails-adding-2-references-of-a-single-model-to-another-model/25612074?noredirect=1#comment40025055_25612074)

Comment: did you try `current_user.houses.create`

Comment: Can you please post code from the controller which saves the data of this form? Also, you need to create user in form? or should it be the `current_user` maybe if you can explain what you wanna do with user, it would help others to understand the flow.

Comment: I have edited the question as required. Please let me know if you need anything else?

Comment: Any reason you need user_id at three places? in `orders`, `from_house`, and `to_house`? Why can't it be just `orders`?

Comment: Its actually in two places (House and Order models). Every house should belong to a user. Each order corresponds to a user. So I need to have user associated with both houses and Order.  I'm trying to build a online moving agency app. An Order should have from and to where the user is moving. Thats the reason why I have from_house and to_house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this change in app/models/order.rb should do the trick:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :from_house, class_name: 'House'
  belongs_to :to_house, class_name: 'House'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :from_house, :to_house

  validates :user, :from_house, :to_house, presence: true

  def from_house_attributes=(attributes)
    fh = build_from_house(attributes)
    fh.user = self.user
  end

  def to_house_attributes=(attributes)
    th = build_to_house(attributes)
    th.user = self.user
  end
end
```

Now, try this in your Rails console:

```
params = { user_attributes: { name: 'New name', email: 'name@example.com' }, from_house_attributes: { name: 'From house name' }, to_house_attributes: { name: 'to house name' } }
o = Order.new(params)
o.save
o.from_house
o.to_house
```

Cheers!